# systemd script for a program won't start up until I login

Tags: systemd

I am trying to run barrier which I installed from snap store on boot after network connection is established. I'm on 19.04.

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/barrier.service
[Unit]
Description=Barrier mouse/keyboard share
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target


[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/snap/bin/barrier.barrierc --enable-crypto --restart --name NUC8i7HVK 192.168.1.155
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This only works automatically after I have logged in to my desktop environment. I want it to work on the login screen itself too so I can use my keyboard and mouse to login. The Ethernet connection "ino1" is made available to other users.

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eno1
```

Thanks,

Comment: The problem is that the application requires a display, and crashes if there isn't a display. Displays are assigned to a user as part of the login process - multiuser.target is too early. Voting to close as a bug report.

Comment: Makes sense. I tried creating a service account called barrier and added "User=barrier" under service. But that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/297). There is [this suggestion](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/179#issuecomment-502170108): create a *user* (with enough permission), autologin and lock the console, ***or*** run as root - all have downfalls, pick your poison.

Someone tried a [hack](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/185#issuecomment-443325702) that worked for them, there are [others](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/179#issuecomment-510380412).

There is no officially supported method.

See also: [How to enable systemd's service without waiting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178920/how-to-enable-systemds-service-without-waiting).